# Bash string to number with number leading with zeros

Tags: bash

Can someone explain how the number `2909` is generated in this bash code? and how to fix it without sed/awk/dc.

```
s="05535"
echo $(( s ))
>> 2909
```

currently have this is my code which I don't like.

```
s=$(echo "$s 0 -p" | dc)
```

Comment: A leading 0 will cause the number to be interpreted as an octal value

Comment: thanks, any easy fix?

Comment: `s=${s#*0}` to remove one leading zero.

Comment: thanks, the easiest I found was $[$s]

Comment: @Cyrus... Don't think that's quite right - try `s=1230123; echo ${s#*0}`, which gives "123". I think you meant simply `${s#0}`, although that won't deal with multiple leading zeros. I'm not sure there's a suitable way to handle multiple zeros with only parameter expansion. Except maybe `$((10#$s))`, which uses the arithmetic context instead...

Comment: @twalberg: You are right. Fix: `s=${s/#0/}`

Answer (score 2):

`2909` is decimal value (base 10) for octal `05535`.

Any number starting from `0` is considered an octal value and `((..))` prints decimal value by default.

To keep number it's decimal value use (thanks to @thatotherguy):

```
s="05535"
echo $(( 10#$s ))
5535
```

Comment: If it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: You can use `echo $((10#$s))`  to force interpretting the number as decimal

Comment: @anubhava: Could you add how to fix it without sed/awk/dc? that other guy's method is probably the most standard way and closest to what is mentioned in `bash(1)`.

Comment: Thanks I added that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other methods, simple **string indexes** can provide both the test and the conversion:

```
[ ${s:0:1} -eq 0 ] && s=${s:1}
```

If you are concerned about multiple leading `0`'s, then

```
 while [ ${s:0:1} -eq 0 ]; do s=${s:1}; done
```